# VSCode: keybindings.json keeps getting overwritten

Tags: visual-studio-code

After modifying keybindings.json, it automatically reverts back to some other settings.

Very simply I would modify keybindings.json, save the file, and close.  Then after a few minutes the new keybindings that I setup are no longer working.  Upon inspecting the keybindings.json file, the changes have been overwritten.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Settings Sync feature is overwriting the keybindings.

VSCode has a Settings Sync feature which synchronizes keybindings across multiple machines.  In settings, go to Application -> Settings Sync -> Keybindings Per Platform.

This setting is set to 'true' by default.  You can set this to 'false' in the UI or settings.json file:

"settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform": false

OR ....

Go to the other machines and make the same modifications so you can still use the sync feature.